# How to show an ActionSheet before the user dismisses the modal

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, alert, swiftui, dismiss

Before the user dismisses the modal by swiping down, there should be an ActionSheet that asks if the user is sure to quit.
It should look similar like Apple is doing it in their Calendar app - when the user swipes down a little bit, an ActionSheet is shown.

[image: ActionSheet]

I already tried using the onDismiss property where I set the state var that determines weather to show the ActionSheet to true:

```swift
@State private var showSheet = false

Button(action: { 
     //some action
})
.sheet(item: //item, 
       onDismiss: {self.showSheet = true},
       content: { 
         //some content 
       })
.actionSheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
     ActionSheet(title: Text("Test"), 
                 message: Text("Are you sure that you want to quit?"), 
                 buttons: [
                           .default(Text("Yes")),
                           .destructive(Text("Cancel"))])}
```

The issue I am encountering is, that this ActionSheet is only shown **after** the user already dismissed the modal.

Comment: You can use BetterSheet from here: https://github.com/egeniq/BetterSheet